# Extract Key From List of Dictionaries in PySpark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe that has a column where the first two rows look like the following.  A list of dictionaries.  However PySpark seems to be interpreting them as strings.

```
[{'id': 213, 'label': 'White', 'option_id': 736, 'option_display_name': 'White Color'}]
[{'id': 23123, 'label': 'Cloud', 'option_id': 736, 'option_display_name': 'Blue Color'}]
```

My goal is to grab the first element of the list (first dictionary) and extract the value for the label key.  I've tried running the following to just grab the first element and I'm getting the following error: (where df is dataframe name and x is column name.

```
df = df.withColumn('color', df.x[0])

AnalysisException: "Can't extract value from option_values#101: need struct type but got string;"
```

I understand that it's likely complaining that this is a string representation of a list, but I'm not sure hot to transform it and then extract the key I want to extract.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your list of dictionary as a json schema and use [from_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html) to extract from it.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, ArrayType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json

df = spark.createDataFrame([('''[{"id": 213, "label": "White", "option_id": "736", "option_display_name": "White Color"}]''', ), 
                            ('''[{"id": 23123, "label": "Cloud", "option_id": "736", "option_display_name": "Blue Color"}]''',)], ['test_col'])
df.printSchema()

schema = ArrayType(StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType()), StructField("label", StringType()),StructField("option_id", StringType()), StructField("option_display_name", StringType()) ]))
df = df.withColumn('color', from_json("test_col", schema)[0]["label"])
df.show()


root
 |-- test_col: string (nullable = true)

+--------------------+-----+
|            test_col|color|
+--------------------+-----+
|[{"id": 213, "lab...|White|
|[{"id": 23123, "l...|Cloud|
+--------------------+-----+
```

Comment: I'm finding that in a lot of cases the wrong array is being chosen.  Is there an easy way to pick the array based on the value of a key?

Comment: can you provide more sample values and a context?